# $\exists k$ s.t. $k^m\le 1^m+2^m+...+(k-1)^m <2\cdot k^m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can it be shown that,for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ there exists at least one $k$ with respect to $m$ such that

$$1\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i^m}{k^m}<2$$

*Example*: let $m=1$ then $k=\{3,4\}$

[Now posted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353224/149083)

Comment: I think $k=2(m+1)$ works.  Note that $\sum_{i=1}^N i^m \approx \frac{N^{m+1}}{m+1}$, so you would need $k$ such that $$k^m\lesssim \frac{k^{m+1}}{m+1}\lesssim 2k^m.$$  This gives you an rough bound: $$m+1\lesssim k\lesssim2(m+1).$$  After testing $k=2(m+1)$ with WolframAlpha, the requirements seem to be met.

Comment: @Batominovski What does this symbol actually mean $\gtrsim$ ?

Comment: @Pruthviraj that particular symbol means "greater than, as well as approximately equal to". However, approximation is subjective. For example, one might agree or disagree that $1\approx 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Note that for large $k$ we have $1^m+\dots+(k-1)^m\geqslant k^m$. Choose minimal $k$ with such property. Then $k>2$ and $2k^m>2(k-1)^m>1^m+\dots+(k-1)^m$ by minimality.

By 'Fedor Petroe' from MO

[Original Answer link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/353225/149083)

Answer (score 2):

I shall prove that $k=2m+2$ works; that is, $$(2m+2)^m \leq \sum_{i=1}^{2m+1}\,i^m < 2\cdot(2m+2)^m\tag{*}$$
for every nonnegative integer $m$.  The inequality on the left is an equality if and only if $m=0$.

First, it can be proven using Bernoulli's Inequality that
$$\frac{i^{m+1}-(i-1)^{m+1}}{m+1} \leq i^m \leq \frac{(i+1)^{m+1}-i^{m+1}}{m+1}$$
for every positive integer $i$ and for every nonnegative integer $m$.  (The only equality case of each inequality above is $m=0$.)  Therefore, it follows that
$$ \frac{N^{m+1}}{m+1}\leq \sum_{i=1}^N\,i^m \leq\frac{(N+1)^{m+1}-1}{m+1}$$
for any nonnegative integer $N$ (with equality case $N=0$ or $m=0$).

Hence, $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{2m+1}\,i^m &\leq \frac{\big((2m+1)+1\big)^{m+1}-1}{m+1}=\frac{(2m+2)^{m+1}-1}{m+1}
\\&<\frac{(2m+2)^{m+1}}{m+1}=\left(\frac{2m+2}{m+1}\right)(2m+2)^{m}=2\cdot(2m+2)^m\,.\end{align}$$
On the other hand, we first note that
$$\left(\frac{2m+1}{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\geq 2^m$$
for all integers $m\geq 0$ (with equality case $m=0$).  This is also due to Bernoulli's Inequality:
$$2^{\frac{m}{m+1}}=(1+1)^{\frac{m}{m+1}}\leq 1+\frac{m}{m+1}\cdot 1=\frac{2m+1}{m+1}\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{2m+1}\,i^m&\geq \frac{(2m+1)^{m+1}}{m+1}\geq \left(\frac{2m+1}{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\cdot\frac{(m+1)^{m+1}}{m+1}
\\&\geq 2^m(m+1)^{m}=(2m+2)^m.\end{align}$$
The equality case of (*) is trivial.

Below is a list of all possible values of $k$ when $m=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

- $m=0$: $k=2$.
- $m=1$: $k=3,4$.
- $m=2$: $k=5,6,7$.
- $m=3$: $k=6,7,8,9$.
- $m=4$: $k=8,9,10,11,12$.
- $m=5$: $k=9,10,11,12,13,14$.

Asymptotically, it can be shown that the smallest value $k_\min$ and the largest value $k_\max$ of $k$ satisfies
$$\frac{k_\min}{m+1}\approx \frac{3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{69}}{12}\approx 1.44222$$
and
$$\frac{k_\max}{m+1}\approx\frac{5}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{213}}{12}\approx 2.46621\,.$$
Therefore, asymptotically, there are $K$ possible values of $k$, where
$$\frac{K}{m+1}\approx \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{213}-\sqrt{69}}{12}\approx 1.02399\,.$$
As far as I see from WolframAlpha,
$$\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{69}}{12}\right)(m+1)+\frac{1}{20}<k_\min <\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{69}}{12}\right)(m+1)+\frac{11}{10}\,,$$
$$\left(\frac{5}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{213}}{12}\right)(m+1)-\frac{19}{20}<k_\max <\left(\frac{5}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{213}}{12}\right)(m+1)+\frac{1}{20}\,,$$
and
$$\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{213}-\sqrt{69}}{12}\right)(m+1)-\frac{9}{10}<K<\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{213}-\sqrt{69}}{12}\right)(m+1)+\frac{19}{20}\,.$$